# Creating a 3d rendering in python with a camera. objects get progressively deformed toward the edge of the screen

Tags: python, pygame, 3d-rendering

So basically, the projection matrix works, as I move the camera arround and look at the cube, there's no problem. But, When I look to the side and the cube should be at the side of the screen, it gets deformed and scaled back.

From what I heard, the projection matrix is supposed to be:

1. translate (points - camera)
2. rotate by - the angles of the camera so that z is foward. x is right and y is up.
   You now have points in a 3d coordinate system of the cameras.
3. divide x/z and y/z so that points twice as far from you become twice closer to each other.

Step one and step two is taken into account into the projection matrix
Step 3 is the perspective.

But as I said, it gets fucked when the object isn't at the middle of the screen

**I tried posting images, but I don'T have the reputation, when I posted links, it says it's spam. I AM forced to upload the code as a whole**

https://jsfiddle.net/PoutineErable/w3z0mtes/69/
This is a version of the code that I modified from a youtube video (in js) that works
(asdw) and (ijkl) for player and mouse movement.

I tried for arround 4 days to get it working,
Today,
I took the second video's code in js and made some light modification that allows movement

using wasd for movement and ijkl for mouse movement, and it works.

Then, I redid my code using the current model.

And Even more stripped down if you want, this has no input, just renders an image. Gotta input the view angle

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
import pygame, sys, random
pygame.init() #Needed to get pygame initiated

print("\n"*20+"-"*11,"start of program","-"*11)
#---------------------------------------------------------Start of math construct
#defining constants
PI = m.pi
WIDTH , HEIGHT = 600, 1000
fov = 70 * PI/180

#initialising the player variables.
player_pos = np.array([0,0,-5])
camera_rot_y = PI/180 * float(input("what's the horizontal angle (degrees)?:"))
camera_rot_x = PI/180 * float(input("what's the vertical angle (degrees)?:"))
camera_rot_z = 0


#defining math functions
def a(x,y): # it's to put (0,0) at the center of the screen
    ''' (num,num) -> (num,num)
    takes a coordinates in cartesian and output the number in shitty 
    coordinates png style
    '''
    return(x + WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2 - y)

def b(array):
    ''' (array or list) -> list
    takes an arrray corresponding to a coordinates in cartesian
    | output the coordinate in array form in a shitty png style'''
    return(a(array[0],array[1]))

def Rx(rot_x):  #The rotation matrix over the x axis
    z   = np.matrix([
    [ 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 0, m.cos(rot_x), m.sin(rot_x), 0],
    [ 0, -m.sin(rot_x), m.cos(rot_x), 0],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
    ])
    return(z)

def Ry(rot_y):#The rotation matrix over the y axis
    z = np.matrix([
    [ m.cos(rot_y), 0,m.sin(rot_y), 0],
    [ 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [ -m.sin(rot_y), 0, m.cos(rot_y), 0],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
    ])
    return(z)

def Rz(rot_z): #The rotation matrix over the z axis
    z = np.matrix([
    [ m.cos(rot_z), m.sin(rot_z), 0, 0],
    [- m.sin(rot_z), m.cos(rot_z), 0, 0],
    [ 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
    ])
    return(z)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------End of math construct.
#initialising the cube:
cube_ini = []

for i in [-1,1]:
    for j in [-1,1]:
        for k in [-1,1]:
            cube_ini.append([i,j,k,1])
cube = np.matrix(np.transpose(cube_ini))

#----------------------------------------------------pygame boiler plate part 2
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("3d_renderer")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#-----------------------------------------------------------Start of animation code
while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.quit()
            #print("The program finished running \n \n")
            sys.exit()


    #Creating the projection matrix
    translation_matrix = np.matrix([[ 1 , 0 , 0 , -player_pos[0]],
                          [ 0 , 1 , 0 , -player_pos[1]],
                          [ 0 , 0 , 1 , -player_pos[2]],
                          [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ]])
    rotation_matrix = np.dot(Ry(-camera_rot_y),Rz(-camera_rot_z))
    rotation_matrix = np.dot(Rx(-camera_rot_x),rotation_matrix)
    projection_matrix = np.dot(rotation_matrix,translation_matrix)


    #making the calculation for the projection of the cube
    pos_cam_proj = np.dot(projection_matrix,cube)
    pos_cam_perspective = np.zeros((8,2))
    for i in range(8):
        pos_cam_perspective[i,0] =  (0.5 * HEIGHT * pos_cam_proj[0,i] * (1/m.tan(fov))) /pos_cam_proj[2,i] 
        pos_cam_perspective[i,1] =  (0.5 * HEIGHT * pos_cam_proj[1,i] * (1/m.tan(fov))) /pos_cam_proj[2,i] 

    cube_screen = np.array(pos_cam_perspective)

    #-----------------------drawing the lines
    screen.fill("Black")
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(i,8): #
            pygame.draw.line(screen, "white", b(cube_screen[i][0:2]),b(cube_screen[j][0:2]))


    #---final two boiler plate lines
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
#------------------------------------------------------------End of animation code
```

The snippet of the code of importance:

```
#Creating the projection matrix
translation_matrix = np.matrix([[ 1 , 0 , 0 , -player_pos[0]],
                      [ 0 , 1 , 0 , -player_pos[1]],
                      [ 0 , 0 , 1 , -player_pos[2]],
                      [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ]])
rotation_matrix = np.dot(Ry(-camera_rot_y),Rz(-camera_rot_z))
rotation_matrix = np.dot(Rx(-camera_rot_x),rotation_matrix)
projection_matrix = np.dot(rotation_matrix,translation_matrix)


#making the calculation for the projection of the cube
pos_cam_proj = np.dot(projection_matrix,cube)
pos_cam_perspective = np.zeros((8,2))
for i in range(8):
    pos_cam_perspective[i,0] =  (0.5 * HEIGHT * pos_cam_proj[0,i] * (1/m.tan(fov))) /pos_cam_proj[2,i] 
    pos_cam_perspective[i,1] =  (0.5 * HEIGHT * pos_cam_proj[1,i] * (1/m.tan(fov))) /pos_cam_proj[2,i] 

cube_screen = np.array(pos_cam_perspective)

#-----------------------drawing the lines
screen.fill("Black")
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(i,8): #
        pygame.draw.line(screen, "white", b(cube_screen[i][0:2]),b(cube_screen[j][0:2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. However, you need to translate the cube instead of rotating it. Just try:

```py
fov = 45 * PI/180
player_pos = np.array([0,0,-4], dtype=np.float32)    # <-- dtype=np.float32
#camera_rot_y = PI/180 * float(input("what's the horizontal angle (degrees)?:"))
#camera_rot_x = PI/180 * float(input("what's the vertical angle (degrees)?:"))
camera_rot_y = 0
camera_rot_x = 0
camera_rot_z = 0

# [...]

angle = 0
while True:
    player_pos[0] = m.sin(m.radians(angle)) * 1.5
    angle += 2

    # [...]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, My code did work. The problem was that I had the wrong fov and I was way too close to the cube object.

```
fov = 60 * PI/180
# [ ... ]
player_pos = np.array([0,0,-10])

# [ ... ]

pos_cam_perspective[i,0] =  0.5 * (1/m.tan(fov/2)) * HEIGHT * pos_cam_proj[0,i]  /pos_cam_proj[2,i] 
pos_cam_perspective[i,1] =  0.5 * (1/m.tan(fov/2)) * HEIGHT  * pos_cam_proj[1,i]  /pos_cam_proj[2,i]
```